# MsBuild XmlPeek result splitting values

Tags: c#, xml, msbuild, split

In my MsBuild script (*.proj) I'm querying C# project using XmlPeek for build configurations and getting the value of Condition attribute of `PropertyGroup`. Here is the working code:

```
      <Target Name="xPeek">
    <XmlPeek Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='msb' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'/&gt;"
             XmlInputPath=" D:\source\MyProject.csproj" 
             Query="/msb:Project/msb:PropertyGroup[contains(@Condition,'Debug')]/@Condition">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Peeked" />
    </XmlPeek>

   <Message Text="%(Peeked.Identity)" />
  </Target>
```

And here is the output:

> 'Release    |AnyCPU' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' 
>   'Release    |AnyCPU' == 'Debug.v9|AnyCPU' 
>   'Release    |AnyCPU' == 'Debug.v10|AnyCPU' 
>   'Release    |AnyCPU' == 'Debug.v101|AnyCPU'

Now I need to split these on `'=='` and I'm confused here that how to create another `ItemGroup` or `PropertyGroup` while splitting the string.

`%(Peeked.Identity).Split('==')` doing nothing.

**Question 1**: How to use Split on this `ItemGroup` while splitting all its values?
**Question 2**: In addition, is it possible to get splitted values from XQuery used in XmlPeek?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XmlPeek task doesn't allow addiontinal Xslt functions to be executed. Unfortunately there are no build-in string functions in msbuild.

I have two solutions for you: One with amn XslTranformation and one with an Exec of a command.

#### XslTransform

You can use the [XslTransformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598688(v=vs.100).aspx) task to take your build file and run a transformation over it leveraging the [substring-before](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256071(v=vs.110).aspx) and [substring-after](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256455(v=vs.110).aspx) xslt functions. The output is stored in a file (test-xslt.out in my case) and with [ReadLinesfromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164299(v=vs.100).aspx) read and converted to Items.

There is one caveat: The variables are not replaced in this scenario whereas for the XmlPeek one they are.

The safexml encoded version looks like this:

```
   <XslTransformation XmlInputPaths = "test-xslttrans.csproj"
      XslContent="
&lt;xsl:stylesheet version=&quot;1.0&quot; xmlns:xsl=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform&quot;
    xmlns:msb=&quot;http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003&quot;
&gt;
   &lt;xsl:output method=&quot;text&quot; indent=&quot;yes&quot; /&gt;

  &lt;xsl:template match=&quot;text()|@*&quot;/&gt;

  &lt;xsl:template match=&quot;/msb:Project/msb:PropertyGroup[contains(@Condition,'Debug')]&quot;&gt;
&lt;xsl:value-of select=&quot;substring-before(@Condition,'==')&quot;/&gt;
&lt;xsl:text&gt;
&lt;/xsl:text&gt;
&lt;xsl:value-of select=&quot;substring-after(@Condition,'==')&quot;/&gt;
&lt;xsl:text&gt;
&lt;/xsl:text&gt;
  &lt;/xsl:template&gt;
&lt;/xsl:stylesheet&gt;   "
      OutputPaths = "test-xslt.out">

    </XslTransformation>

    <ReadLinesFromFile
              File="test-xslt.out" >
              <Output
                  TaskParameter="Lines"
                  ItemName="SplittedPeek"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <Message Text="%(SplittedPeek.Identity)" />
```

for convenience here is the plain xslt:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/msb:Project/msb:PropertyGroup[contains(@Condition,'Debug')]" >
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@Condition,'==')"/>
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@Condition,'==')"/>
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Command Exec

This solution writes your Peeked values to a file. By invoking the FOR /F commamnd of the command processor we can parse lines and split them within some strict boundaries which fitted well here. The output of the EXEC is written to a file split.txt. The ReadLinesFromFiles is used to read the values in an Item.

```
 <WriteLinesToFile
          File="test-xslt-write.out"
          Lines="@(Peeked)"
          Overwrite="true"
          Encoding="ASCII"/>

 <Exec Command="for /f &quot;tokens=1* delims==&quot; %%a in (test-xslt-write.out) do @echo %%a > split.txt"/>
 <Exec Command="for /f &quot;tokens=1* delims==&quot; %%a in (test-xslt-write.out) do @echo %%b >> split.txt"/>

<ReadLinesFromFile
          File="test-xslt.out" >
          <Output
              TaskParameter="Lines"
              ItemName="SplittedCmdPeek"/>
</ReadLinesFromFile>

<Message Text="%(SplittedCmdPeek.Identity)" />
```